# App throwing an exception when trying to save text using PCLStorage NuGet Package

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am learning C# and Xamarin Forms along with it and am currently making a simple practice Contacts app. I’ve been trying to use a NuGet package called PCLStorage. However, I am running into problems when I click the Add Contact button and the method to save the info is called.

```
    async Task StoreInfoAsync(Contact tempContact)
    {
        string folderName = "ContactsFolder";
        string fileName = "contacts.txt";

        IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync(folderName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        await file.WriteAllTextAsync(tempContact.ToString());
    }

    async void Handle_Clicked_Add(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        nameLabel.Text = name.Text;         //name and phone are entry fields on the screen
        phoneLabel.Text = phone.Text;

        newContact.Name = name.Text;        //newContact is an instance of the Contact class which has name and phone properties
        newContact.Phone = phone.Text;

        await StoreInfoAsync(newContact);
    }
```

This code is in my AddContacts code-behind class. Here the "Handle_Clicked_Add" method is called whenever I click the Add Contact button on the screen, which in turn calls the StoreInfoAsync method. However, when it calls that StoreInfoAsync method, the app throws the following exception:

```
This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the PCLStorage NuGet Package from you main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.
```

I’ve looked up solutions for this and what I keep seeing mostly is that I need to include the PCLStorage package in the PCL solution as well as the Android and iOS solutions, and I’ve already done that but the error still persists.

I also saw some stuff about how this package uses the bait and switch technique, where the PCL has the bait and at runtime it gets switched out with platform specific implementation. The only problem is that I’m not too familiar with C# and I’m trying to learn it by myself, so I don’t know how to implement this bait and switch technique by myself and create my own implementations for everything.

Any input or solution is welcome.

Comment: In your packages.config for this project what is your target framework version?            
E.g. 


`<package id="PCLStorage" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />`

Comment: This is what I have in the packages.config in the portable project: `<package id="PCLStorage" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />`

Comment: Try replacing targetFramework with platform-specific. E.g. if you are running it on windows try putting `net45` there and run `Update-Package -Reinstall`. This will create dependency on platform-specific DLL which should have required functionality (according to the error message). You can swap this DLL later for iOS one in your iOS delivery